# What is the forward slash inside brackets in Java initializer meaning?

Tags: java, syntax

I was researching how to encrypt and decrypt data with AES encryption and came across the following bit of syntax: `byte[] iv = new byte[128/8];`

The part I'm confused about is the `[128/8]`.

I've never seen this syntax before with the forward slash in the brackets. I've done several searches but I can't find any references to this type of syntax. Can someone tell me what it means?

Comment: It will really help your programming to study a Java book.

Comment: BTW, there is no such thing as a "forward slash". there is a "slash" and a "backslash", that its a MS'ism. See [ASCII / ISO 8859-1 - Latin-1 Table](https://cs.stanford.edu/~miles/iso8859.html) and per unicode "SOLIDUS" and "REVERSE SOLIDUS", [Slash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slash_(punctuation)) and [Backslash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backslash).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just a division operator. The value of the constant expression is `128/8` or 16. The author is evidently trying to express that the array is going to hold 128 bits.

Comment: Okay... I was reading too much into it. I feel that the author wrote this poorly, but now I see the point.

Comment: @RyanH. No there author did not write this poorly, it is a common idiom, clear and straight forward Java.